# What is the purpose of "q" in Safe Prime definition during key pair generation?

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, key-generation, safe-prime

Consider the following case, given **x**(private key) and **y**(public key), how to determine whether this key pair is generated by a pre-defined Safe Prime Group(Say FFDHE, RFC 7919)?

In context of [SP800 56Ar3 Section 5.6.1.1.4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar3.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A94%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C96%2C700%2C0%5D), my understanding is we need to check 2 conditions,

```
i. y = g^x mod p
ii. 1 < x < min(2^N, q-1)

where N is the max bit size of private key can generate
```

(i) makes sense because if I change **p** and **g**, x and y will fail the key verification.

However, in (ii), if I completely ignore q(makes 1 < x < 2^N), or change value q(makes q != (p-1)/2), I still can pass this key verification method. **q** seems is only used to bound the range of **x** to [1, min(2^N, q-1)]. Is there any more meaning for this **q** in key generation phase?

My understanding of Safe Prime key pair generation are following, please correct me if I am wrong, thanks.

Phase 1: Generate DH parameters **p**, **q**, **g**. Here requires **q** to hold properties of

```
1. g^q = 1 mod p, 
2. q = (p-1)/2
3. q is a prime
```

Since RFC defines the exact **p**, **q**, **g** to use, so we don't consider this phase.

Phase 2: Use **p**, **q**, **g** to generate Key Pair **x** and **y**. In this phase, SP800 56A bounds the range of **x** to [1, min(2^N, q-1)], what if I generate a larger **x** that, q < x < 2^N ? Is this just FIPS document wants it or there are some underlie mathematical meaning behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key generation/validation procedure considered supports the two kinds of parameters explained in [Section 5.5.1.1 FFC Domain Parameter Selection/Generation](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar3.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A80%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C96%2C464%2C0%5D):

> a class of “safe” domain parameters (…)
> and a class of “FIPS 186-type” domain parameters (…)

In the former case, $2q+1=p$, and typical parameters could be $2^{2047}<p<2^{2048}$, $N=256$. In that case $2^N<q$ and $q$ plays no role in the key generation/validation procedure, as noted in the question. Notice that if we used $N=2048$ (also possible, though not believed to much increase security), $q$ would come into play.

In the later case, better known a Schnorr group, $r\,q+1=p$ for some large $r$. Typical parameters could be $2^{2047}<p<2^{2048}$, $2^{255}<q<2^{256}$, $N=256$. In that case $2^N>q$ and $N$ plays no role in the key generation/validation procedure. Notice that if we used $N=224$ (also possible, and not believed to much lower security), $N$ would come into play.

> What if I generate a larger $x$ that, $q < x < 2^N$ ?

Mathematically that's fine as long as $x\bmod q$ is not too poorly distributed. When used as exponent (modulo $p$), $x$ will produce the same result as $x'=x\bmod q$, thus no compatibility issue is to fear, except if the private key gets transmitted to another device: conforming implementations will reject $x\ge q$ when importing a key.

When it comes to performance, shorter $x$ tend to be better.